# noVNC console on Openstack Dashboard is rendering garbled UI on RHEL7

Tags: python, redhat-enterprise-linux, openstack, libvirt

I am running nova-compute on RHEL7. Openstack dashboard's noVNC console is rendering garbled UI for any instance having a UI console. Can somebody please help out? This is working just fine on RHEL65

[image: Nova VM Grabbed instance]